# The Method UserBean is undefiend for the JSP file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

the error i get is:

```
The method UserBean(Object) is undefined for the type UserLogged_jsp
```

the code it is pointing to is:

```
<% UserBean currentUser = (UserBean (session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser")));%> 
Welcome <%= currentUser.getFirstName() + " " + currentUser.getLastName() %>
```

i have included the UserBean java file:

```
<%@import ="org.login.UserBean" %>
```

i just don't get where the problem is.

Comment: Cast like this `(UserBean)`, in the line `UserBean currentUser = (UserBean (session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser")));`.

Comment: @βнɛƨн Ǥʋяʋиɢ: if you would have made this an answer you would have had my upvote (even if it's just a simple fix, it's still the right answer)

Comment: @βнɛƨнǤʋяʋиɢ : Post it answer and mussi89 you accept it as correct. Its good practice.

Comment: @HardikMishra sure as soon as answer is posted!!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<% UserBean currentUser = ((UserBean) (session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser")));%> 
   Welcome <%= currentUser.getFirstName() + " " + currentUser.getLastName() %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your import statement.
<%@ page import ="org.login.UserBean" %>. 
it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% UserBean currentUser = ((UserBean) (session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser")));%> 
   Welcome <%= currentUser.getFirstName() + " " + currentUser.getLastName() %>
```

Also check:

```
<%@ page language="java" 
         contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1256"
         pageEncoding="windows-1256"
         import="your.package.name.UserBean"
%>
```